# e.target detected on CLICK, not on ROLL_OVER

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a container with several movieclips in. I added an eventlistener to the container and on roll over i trace the e.target.name. The problem is when i roll over the e.target.name is the name of the container, while when i click the e.target.name is the target of the object inside the container. Anyone know how to solve this?

```
filmsContent.StateBtnContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, stateRollOverHandler);
filmsContent.StateBtnContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stateClick);


    private function stateRollOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace(e.target.name);
    }
    private function stateClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace(e.target.name);
    }
```

Comment: well, i see a rather obvious typo - assuming that's a straight copy/paste from your code.  if it is i'm surprised it even compiled.  you're missing a closing bracket and semicolon at the end of your event listener addition for stateClick.

Comment: hmm, indeed, the code is fine here, no idea what happened while pasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the differences between `target` and `currentTarget` on `MouseEvent` object.
In your code, if you use `currentTarget` instead of `target` property you will get in both case get the container object (StateBtnContainer)

Here is a quick example that illustrates the differences :

```
var container : Sprite = new Sprite();
container.name="container";
container.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
container.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
container.graphics.endFill();
addChild(container);

var child : Sprite = new Sprite();
child.name="child";
child.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
child.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
child.graphics.endFill();
container.addChild(child);
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e : MouseEvent) : void {
    trace("click",e.target.name);
    trace("click",e.currentTarget.name);
});
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(e : MouseEvent) : void {
    trace("roll over",e.target.name);
    trace("roll over",e.currentTarget.name);
});
```

Comment: if i want the name of the different objects in my container than e.target is the way to go no? But i figured out the problem, apperently the objects dont get noticed when i use ROLL_OVER, it is working with MOUSE_OVER now. Dunno why ROLL_OVER dont work.

Comment: MOUSE_OVER and ROLL_OVER are differents : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:mouseOver http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:rollOver